# How to execute sql stored procedure with multiple date parameters using sqlalchemy in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy, pymssql

**I am able to execute stored procedure without parameters:**

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy
import pyodbc
import datetime as dt  

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql+pymssql://MyServer/MyDB')
df = pd.read_sql_query('EXEC dbo.TestProcedure' , engine)  # stored procedure without parameters
print(df)
```

**But unable to execute stored procedure with parameters:**

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy
import pyodbc
import datetime as dt  

myparams = ['2017-02-01','2017-02-28', None]  # None substitutes NULL in sql

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql+pymssql://MyServer/MyDB')
df = pd.read_sql_query('EXEC PythonTest_Align_RSrptAccountCurrentMunich @EffectiveDateFrom=?,@EffectiveDateTo=?,@ProducerLocationID=?', engine, params=myparams)
print(df)
```

**Error message:**

```
  File "src\pymssql.pyx", line 465, in pymssql.Cursor.execute
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pymssql.ProgrammingError) (102, b"Incorrect syntax near '?'.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n")
[SQL: EXEC PythonTest_Align_RSrptAccountCurrentMunich @EffectiveDateFrom=?,@EffectiveDateTo=?,@ProducerLocationID=?]
[parameters: ('2017-02-01', '2017-02-28', None)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

How can I pass parameters using `sqlalchemy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are executing a raw SQL query with parameter placeholders then you must use the [paramstyle](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle) supported by the DBAPI layer. pymssql used the "format" paramstyle `%s`, not the "qmark" paramstyle `?` (which pyodbc uses).

However, you can avoid the ambiguity by wrapping the query in a SQLAlchemy `text` object and consistently use the "named" paramstyle. SQLAlchemy will automatically translate the parameter placeholders to the appropriate style for the DBAPI you are using. For example, to call a stored procedure named `echo_datetimes`:

```python
import datetime
import sqlalchemy as sa

# ...

query = sa.text("EXEC echo_datetimes @p1 = :param1, @p2 = :param2")
values = {'param1': datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
          'param2': datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)}
df = pd.read_sql_query(query, engine, params=values)
print(df)
#              dt_start              dt_end
# 0 2020-01-01 01:01:01 2020-02-02 02:02:02
```

Answer (score 0):

Read_sql is just for reading tables. To execute someting with parameters try using

engine.execute(your sql query)#you can try entering with parameters as how you give 
                              in your sql
engine.execution_options(autocommit=True)